# database logic, querying a table with repeated values

Tags: sql, database

I'm sorry it was hard to come up with a descriptive title.

I have a two column table with a composite key --> ids and attributes.
So an id may appear twice in the table but each instance with a different attribute.

```
id    attribute
1     1
1     2
2     2
3     1
```

My question is on how to query this. For example I want to find all ids that match two attributes

```
SELECT a.id
FROM   table AS a, table AS b
WHERE  a.attribute = 1
AND    b.attribute = 2
AND    a.id = b.id
```

So this query should only return id 1.

That's very rigid because I need to know how many attributes I'll be searching for ahead of time, although dynamically creating the SQL is probably possible.

Is there a better way of querying a table like this? Is there a better way of structuring this table in the first place?

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT id
FROM   table
WHERE  attribute in (1,2)
group by id
having count(id) = 2
```

This assumes that the same attribute can only be assigned exactly once to an id (the combination id/attribute is unique)

[SQLFiddle example](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!1/6aaa1/1)

Answer (score 0):

You can do a *table rotation* and create a flat view of the data, something like the following. The drawback is that you have to impose a fixed limit on the number of columns in the result. Here's an example:

```
create view flat_attributes
as
select id ,
       attr_1 = t1.attribute ,
       attr_2 = t2.attribute ,
       attr_3 = t3.attribute ,
       ...
       attr_N = tN.attribute
from ( select distinct
              id
       from attributes
     ) t
left join attributes t1 on t1.id = t.id and t1.attribute = 1
left join attributes t2 on t2.id = t.id and t1.attribute = 2
left join attributes t3 on t3.id = t.id and t1.attribute = 3
...
left join attributes tN on tN.id = t.id and tN.attribute = N
```

any `attr` column that is non null means that the `id` in question has that attribute. It should simplify the querying.